# Using Float values in Imagedraw

Tags: python, image, generator, python-imaging-library

Is there a way to set PIL and by extension Imagedraw to allow float values for such commands as Arc and Ellipse? I am running into major problems and cannot do what I need to do because of the seeming requirement that angles and bounding box position specifiers must be integers, and I cannot use a different package, nor is approximating everything with short straight lines a viable alternative either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want sub-pixel positioning, one possible-if-inefficient solution would be to scale everything up by a factor of, say, 10, rounding (original_floating_point_coordinates * 10) to integers, then resize the whole image back down at the end. Doesn't help with angles, I suppose.